# Restriction of a linear map on a compact convex subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with non-empty interior

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, functional-equations

Let $f: \Omega \to \mathbb{R}$, where $\Omega$ is a convex compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ with a non-empty interior, denoted by $Int(\Omega)$. Assume that on $Int(\Omega)$, $f$ is the restriction of a linear function $L: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$. Is $f$ necessarily the restriction of $L$ to $\Omega$ ?

Note that $f$ is not assumed continuous on the frontier of $\Omega$.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Please show your try.

Comment: Consider the case $n=1$. Can you figure out what happens in this case?

Comment: Well, if $f$ is not assumed to be continuous on the boundary, then it can literally be defined on it in any way you like. In infinitely many ways. But there's only one way that makes it linear.

Comment: Indeed, this was a stupid question. If $f$ is not assumed continuous, I can define it arbitrarily on the boundary, so that it does not necessarily correspond to the restriction of $L$ on $\Omega$. On the other hand, if $f$ is assumed continuous on the boundary, the continuity of $L$ implies that $f$ must coincide with $L$ also on the boundary.

Comment: @Peter Well, for that you still need to prove that the closure of $\mathrm{Int}(\Omega)$ is $\Omega$, which if I’m not mistaken is true under the conditions you wrote down, but is not completely obvious.

Comment: I agree, but I did not think it was relevant to mention this in my previous comment; maybe it was a mistake. In any vector space, the closure of the interior of a convex set with non-empty interior is the closure of this set. As $\Omega$ is closed, the conclusion follows.